# Building a domain from a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a url from a string. I can do this if the domain is hard coded into the formula, however I am trying to get the domain from a Cell in a sheet and can not work it out

```
'''This works
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
 ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=(""https://www.google.com/""&SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")"
```

This Also work if the cell that keeps changing is on the same sheet, WHICH IT WILL NOT BE.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
ws.Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=($Z$1 &SUBSTITUTE(b2, "" "", """")&"" "")"
```

However I want it to get the domain from a cell in sheet2 b2, this way I can keep changing the domain.

```
'''These do Not work
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
 ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=(Sheets(Sheet2.Range(""B2"")) &SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")"

'ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=(Sheet2.Range(""B2"") &SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")"

'ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=(Sheets(Sheet2.Range(""$B$2"")) &SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")"

'ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=(Sheet2.Range(""$B$2"") &SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")"
```

Results

[image: Results]

Formula in Formula bar in excel

[image: Formula]

As Advised I can produce the domain if hard coded, but not if i am trying to take the domain from a cell in sheet 2.

**Question** -  Can someone please advsied how I can do this? (formula or via vba)

As always thanks in advance

' #################     Update   ##############

Thanks to ed2 guidance below this worked

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
ws.Range("I2:I" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=Sheet2!$B$2&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"" "", """")&"" """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution used

```
=Sheet2!$b$2&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"" "", """")&"" """
```

### Reason

VBA and Excel have different ways of referencing a range on another sheet. Those ways are not interchangeable.

### Another issue

It looks likely that you are accidentally putting the whole VBA formula builder in as the formula. This is because you are surrounding with text qualifiers `"`. Try removing those text qualifiers from your code to see what happens. You will need to reinstate them around *only* any text such as the `=` at the start of the formula.

For example, the line (from "these do not work") containing:

```
"=(Sheets(Sheet2.Range(""B2"")) &SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")"
```

Should this instead contain:

```
"=" & (Sheets(Sheet2.Range(""B2"")) &SUBSTITUTE(B2, "" "", """")&"" "")
```

### If still trouble, try this

Otherwise, try it manually in excel first. Then build it with VBA.

Your formula bar says

```
=(Sheet2.Range("B2") &SUBSTITUTE(B2, " ", "")&" ")
```

Try making it say:

```
=Sheet2!B2&SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","")&" ")
```

VBA and Excel have different ways of referencing a range on another sheet. Those ways are not interchangeable.

I am also not clear on what exactly you are achieving with:

- Substitute (hint: check out the TRIM function)
- Your concatenation joins 3 things into a text string

Comment: Thanks ed2 this worked for me `=Sheet2!$b$2&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"" "", """")&"" """ ` Thanks for the Trim function advice I will have a look at it